# Approximating by Exponential (1+x) Raised to Large Power

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

It is fairly elementary that close to $x=0$, and in the limit as $\zeta$ becomes large (perhaps hundreds or thousands), $\exp(\zeta x)$ is a good approximation to $(1+x)^\zeta$. But within what range of $x$ is this so? It is easy to find writings on how it is that the exponential function $\exp z$ is

$$\lim_{n→∞}{(1+\frac{z}{n})^n}$$,

but all the texts I have found that expound this seem loathe to give an estimate of *just how good* an approximation this is, and how small x must be for the approximation to be *so-&-so* good.

I made an attempt to estimate the error, by  considering the expansions for each, looking at which terms in the expansion give the biggest contribution, & by using the identity

$$-(1-x)\ln(1-x)=x(1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k(k+1)})$$

for $|x|<1$ to get the approximation

$$\frac{p^n}{(p)_n}≈\sqrt{1-\frac{n}{p}}\exp(n\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(\frac{n}{p})^k}{k(k+1)}})$$,

where $(p)_n$ is the *descending **pochhammer*** symbol. I'm fairly sure (depending on whether I overlooked any significant terms in usings *Stirling's formula* (which is alltoo easy to do)), that this expression is *pretty* good for all *n* from 0 through *p--1*. You have to 'cheat' *everso* slightly at n=p, though, as if you just substitute it the *square root* bit becomes 0 instead of 1/√(2πp).

The conclusion I came to is that for small $x$, $\exp(\zeta x)$ exceeds $(1+x)^\zeta$ by a factor of approximately

$$\exp(\frac{\zeta x^2}{2})$$.

So if the *proportion* tolerance be $\epsilon$, then the approximation would be valid in the range bounded by

$$x=±\sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon}{\zeta}}$$,

which I think seems intuitively quite reasonable.

**Update**

I have been apprised (see comments) of my having used a utterly barbarous method! Overlooking the simple method was a bit *barmy*, really; but at least there were spin-offs - most particularly that expression for $(p)_n/p^n$. And it shows how with the exponential function | factorial | Pochhammer & all that the threads can just go allover the place & yet *always* join-up end-to end eventually.

There is a difference between the expression gotten by the simple correct method & the one gotten by my *barbarous* method. Whereas in the correct method, the series constituting the argument of the exponential is that for

$$x-\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k}$$

in my *barbarous* solution it's

$$x+(1-x)\ln(1-x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k(k-1)}$$

The reason for this is when calculating the factor (<1) by which the exponential is multiplied to get the binomial, I just calculated the factor by which the *maximum term* of the exponential (the term at k (the index of the terms) = $\zeta x$). This gives only the first term - the *quadratic* - correctly: the series is already wrong at the *cubic* term, which has a coefficient of +1/6 instead of -1/3. However, the cubic term can be 'restored' by the simple expedient of taking the mean of an exponential weighted  by a Gaussian. As the argument ($\zeta x$ in this case) of an exponential becomes large, the distribution of the size of terms with respect to index (k) tends to Gaussian with mean *and* variance $\zeta x$. So assuming an exponential with stepth $\ln(1-x)$, as in the region of the maximum term, each term is ~(1-x)× the preceding one, we find a correction (and there is no need to do any integration) by noting that the product of the Gaussian & the exponential is

$$\exp(-\frac{k^2}{2\zeta x}+k\ln(1-x))$$

$$=\exp(-\frac{(k-\zeta x\ln(1-x))^2}{2\zeta x}+\frac{\zeta x\ln(1-x)^2}{2})$$

I'll leave out how because we are integrating from -∞ to +∞ with respect to *k*, it is immaterial that the Gaussian is *shifted* along the k axis, and we are just left with the correction factor

$$=\exp(\frac{\zeta x\ln(1-x)^2}{2})$$

≈

$$=\exp(\frac{\zeta x^3}{2})$$.

When we divide *my barbarous* final expression by this (*divide* rather than multiply, as we have just here been treating the matter *reciprocal-wise*), the coefficient of the cubic term becomes 1/6 - 1/2 = -1/3 - *the correct value*!!

I find it interesting that when you use the *very crude* approximation of taking the *peak* term of the expansion of the exponential as the typical term, you only get the result correct as far as the quadratic term in the final expression; but that you can extend correctitude as far as the *cubic* term by the simple expedient of averaging an exponential weighted by a Gaussian.

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Comment: Thanks for that ... coz some parts of the reasoning seemed a tad ... _fragile_ shall we say!

Comment: The easiest derivation might be to write $(1+x)^N$ as $exp(N*log(1+x)$. If you then approximate the logarithmic term by its Taylor series for small $x$, you arrive at the multiplicative correction factor $exp(0.5*N*x^2)$. Anyway, well done !

Comment: I did it what was probably a _long way round_: noting that the terms in the exponential expansion that give the biggest contribution are in the vicinity of k=ζx (_k_ the _index_ of a term), and that these are in the _binomial_ expansion diminished by $(ζ)_(ζx)/ζ^(ζx)$ because of the 'counting-down' in the binomial expansion, approximating this ratio using _Stirling's theorem_ & that _logarithm_ identity; & then just _hoping_ that the spread of significantly-contributing terms about the maximally-contributing one should be sufficiently small (√(ζx)) that these would preponderate.

Comment: Your method is just so obvious I ought not to have missed it. I also notice my method gives a result that's very different bey5ond the first (quadratic) term. That "hoping they would preponderate bit is clearly flawed, I see now, as the terms on the series about thr

Comment: the biggest term in series of an exponential with large argument have a  pretty-close-to-Gaussian distribtion, and the factor multiplying these terms to diminish them changes roughly _exponentially across_ that Gaussian; and in that case the mean factor certainly departs considerably from it's value in the centre of the Gaussian: so that assumption was very hasty, really

Comment: I'll stop soon now. I love all these exponentials & factorials & Pochhammer symbols - the way the threads go all over the place ... & then _yet_ still join-up end-to-end. If you take the mean over the Gaussuan, you get a correction factor of exp(ζx.ln(1-x)^2) that _precisely undoes_ what I did to get that series for the Pochhamner symbol (ie taking the difference of successive coefficients of the series for ___ln()___, & restores the _plain simple __ln()___ series, which is what you get using _your_ method. So it ends uo at the same point anyway!

Comment: Or only as far as the ^3 term, maybe. At least you restore that much. I'll leave it now. I've had an admonishment already for having overly prolonged discussions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to this forum. First of all I want to command you for posting this question, which to me demonstrates that you have a keen interest and enthusiasm for mathematics and the willingness to search for answers by using your own methods. I think it is excellent that you arrive at the correct result, and then manage to rephrase it all (in a humorous way!), in response to my short comment.

The title of your question indicates that you want to explore the relationship between the function $(1+x)^N$ (with $x$ small and $N$ large) and the exponential function $e^{Nx}$.

In the text of the question you chose a slightly better formulation, namely the relation between $(1 + x/N)^N$ and $e^x$, where $x$ is now any real number and $N$ is large. This version is preferable because if we now take $x = -5$, then by taking $N$ large enough we avoid the problem of a negative number raised to a power.

The comparison between these two function is most easily done by expressing both of them as a power of $e$. The first then becomes $e^{N*log(1+x/N)}$. We now write $y = x/N$ and expand the logarithm in a Taylor series. This yields:

$$log(1+y) = y - {y^2}/2 + {y^3}/3 - {y^4}/4 + {y^5}/5...$$

Taking just the first term (which is equivalent to taking the large N limit) yields $e^x$, as expected. Hence the next terms form the correction that we seek. We can write:

$$log(1 + y) - y = -{y^2}/2 * [1 - (2/3)y + (2/4)y^2 - (2/5)y^3 +…]$$

For a crude estimate of the correction it is usually sufficient to consider the first term, which is $-{y^2}/2$. However the simplicity of the series and the fact that successive terms alter in sign, makes it possible to seek even better estimates. If we consider that the factor (2/4) differs only little from (4/9), it is tempting to write the correction term as:

$$log(1+y) - y = -3y^2/(6+4y)$$

This formula works very well. It turns out that the error in this approximation is a roughly a factor $100$ smaller than in the previous one.

Comment: ¶ I very much appreciate your gracious welcome to this site! You have rightly perceived that mathematics is a matter in which I find a _sublime beauty_ - even a _spiritual_ significance. ¶ That rational expression for approximating the logarithm series: it brings to mind the famous _Padé_ approximation method ... and also various other remarkable rational approximations, some of which are probably Padé ones, others of which are possibly just serendipitous: there are instances of this in _Abramowitz & Stegun_ one for the _erf function_ is one that I find particularly remarkable.